# Return status of python unittest

Tags: windows, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm trying to call a unittest from another python file, and evaluate the exit code.  I was able to use `unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule` and `unittest.TextTestRunner.run` to call the unittest from another python file, but that's returning the entire results to the cmd.  I would like to simply set a variable equal to the status code so I can evaluate it.  I was able to find a method unittest.TestResult.wasSuccessful, but I'm having trouble implementing it.  When I add it to the use case, I get the following AttributeError: `AttributeError: 'ConnectionTest' object has no attribute 'failures'`

I've included some code samples below and a mockup of the desired result as an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve.  Thank you in advance.

```
""" Tests/ConnectionTest.py """

import unittest
from Connection import Connection


class ConnectionTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_connection(self):
        #my tests

    def test_pass(self):
        return unittest.TestResult.wasSuccessful(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


""" StatusTest.py """

import unittest
import Tests.ConnectionTest as test
#import Tests.Test2 as test2
#import Tests.Test3 as test3
#import other unit tests ...

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)


""" Return True if unit test passed
"""
def test_passed(test):
    if test.test_pass() == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

""" Run unittest for each module before using it in code
"""
def main():
    tests = "test test2 test3".split()
    for test in tests:
        if test_passed(test):
            # do something
        else:
            # log failure
            pass
```

**Update**

To put the question more simply, I need to set the highlighted variable below to the highlighted value.

[image: goal]

Comment: Please include your code as text in the body of your question.  It's easier to read, available to accessibility tools, can be copied, and allows people who can't access imgur at work to help you too.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh sorry about that, I'll update momentarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you tried implementing `result.wasSuccessful`, but would something like the following work:

```
result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
test_exit_code = int(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

The value of `test_exit_code` would then be either 0 when the test suite ran successfully or 1 otherwise.

If you want to disable the output of the `TextTestRunner` you can specify your own stream, such as:

```
from io import StringIO

result = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=StringIO(), verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you will! That worked.  I changed the verbosity parameter in TextTestRunner, but it's still printing 'Ran x tests in xs' and the 'OK'. Is there a way to suppress that print/ output?

Comment: Glad it worked. So you're also looking to suppress all the console output?

Comment: Yes, what i'm basically looking to do is have logic in my main script that will call a class/ method if it's corresponding unit test passed, or not call the class/method if it doesnt.  For that, i just need to set the unit test status code == var and then use the var in an if then in my other script.  So in short, yes, i dont need the console output for the unit test

Comment: I see. So presumably you could use the approach above - `result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)` but pass an individual test rather than the whole suite in order to get a pass/fail answer for that test. As for disabling the output, you can specify your own `stream` argument to the `TextTestRunner` - see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Will.   Your answer was perfect.